# Ansible Fatal error while gather facts, "module_stderr": "Shared connection closed

Tags: ansible

I am getting fatal error while execution on playbook, while 1st step of gather facts this error is coming & entire facts is displayed after error.
Following os the error,

My ansible version is v2.9 with Python v2.7.5

```
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 'IP address of host' closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "\u001b7\u001b[r\u001b[999;999H\u001b[6n\r\nresize: Time out occurred\r\r\n\u001b[H\u001b[2JServer: hostname\r\n\r\nDatabases Installed:\r\n\r\n12.1.0.2.170117 - 5 - gdb1hc1 gdb1ic1 gdb1rc1 gdb2ic1 gdb2rc1\r\n\r\nDatabases started:\r\n\r\n\r\nNumber of stated DB : 0\r\nNumber of installed DB : 5\r\n\r\nListeners started:\r\n\r\n\r\n[YOU HAVE NEW MAIL]\r
```